# Cannot import sos package in python2

Tags: python, rhel8

I am trying to import the sos package in python2 in rhel8.3 but I get the following error

```
[root@svr_1 site-packages]# python2.7
Python 2.7.17 (default, Aug 18 2020, 09:42:29)
[GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sos
```

The rpm for the package is already installed.

```
[root@svr_1 site-packages]# yum list installed | grep sos
sos.noarch                                        3.9.1-6.el8                                  @InstallMedia
[root@svr_1 site-packages]#
```

Does anyone have any idea. In rhel7 this was OK.

Comment: As mentioned https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=sos sos.noarch is a set of tools and not a python module/package. Can you search for `python2-sos`?

Comment: on rhel7 ```[root@svr_1 ~]# python2
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sos
>>>
```

Comment: So as far as I see you have multiple versions of python2 and when you install the sos you get it for a other version of python.

The best is to install pip for your python2.7 https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Then you can install sos `python2.7 -m pip install sos`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing same issue. Default python for rhel8 is python 3. So python packages will be under /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages when installing a rhel8 package and can be used from python 3.

```
 [root@svr_1 plugins]# python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 18 2020, 08:33:21)
[GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sos
>>>
```